# Migrating Packages.config to PackageReference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, migrate

I trying to Migrate WPF .Net framework to WPF .netcore
So I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/core/porting/), So I tried migrating Packages.config to PackageReference

I also follow the rule. 
My project is c# wpf, (NOT asp.net)

[image: my .net framwork version]

and my .Net framework verison is over 4.7.2,
My visual studio version is 2019.

but, I clicked the migrate option,

[image: It's translated english]

There an error. But I couldn't find any solutions.

I have to migrate to .net core
someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of ways to convert to .net core wpf.

***Solution***:

1. Create new .net core wpf Project
2. Copy files which only cs, xaml in .net framework written
3. Paste all that you copied at you project that you create step 0
4. Open your .net core project and change the project namespace as same as you pasted csharp files.
5. Now done!

It really, really worked for me great.